# Подвинуть image относительно родительской image в сторону (healthBar) Unity 2d c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

[image: Представьте,что они наложены друг на друга]Нужно реализовать healthBar двигая дочерний зеленый прямоугольник по отношению к красному родительскому.

PS Просьба не предлагать другие варианты,я знаю о них,нужно именно так.

PSS мб код поможет,который есть сейчас

```
SliderRect.transform.localScale = new Vector3 ( currentHealth / maxHealth, 1.1f, 1);
if(SliderRect.transform.localPosition.x == 0f)
{
     SliderRect.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-(1 - (currentHealth / maxHealth)), 0,- 0.001f);
}
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что не работает или что работает не так? При реализации вложенными image скорей всего понадобится использовать маску, вы пробовали? Скрин или рисунок ожидаемого результата был бы тоже очень полезен.

Comment: Добавил пример с картинкой - Представьте,что они наложены друг на друга

Comment: Что имеете в виду под фразой "по отношению к красному родительскому"? Делаете зеленый дочерним, и соответственно нулевые координаты это "полное" состояние healthbar'а, а ширина красного это расстояние на которое нужно сдвинуть зеленый чтобы получить "пустое" состояние.

Comment: Проблема в том,что если изменить scale то фигура измениться с обеих сторон в сторону своего центра.Я пытался решить проблему изменением scale + transform влево.Но ,к сожалению,это работает не так как хотелось.

В итоге: я решил проблему изменив префаб heathbar"a,но это уже костыли,так сказать.Хотелось бы узнать есть ли возможность сделать это без костылей:)

Comment: @TEA вам не нужно scale менять, вам нужно позицию дочернего объекта изменять

Comment: Если правильно понял, можно зеленый поставить дочерним к красному, выставить ему корректные якоря, и менять Scale.